# How should I approach the scholarship committee for reconsideration if they have rejected my application?

Tags: funding, undergraduate

I applied for a scholarship at Ecole Polytechnique in France and received a rejection early this morning. I want the committee to reconsider my application but I can't find a good enough reason apart from saying that I will not be able to attend the institution without financial support. I have been admitted to another university (HKU) with a handsome scholarship and I was wondering if informing them about this might work. Any advice about this issue would be much appreciated.

Comment: Honestly, I doubt a committee would reconsider an application once the decision is made, even with the added information that you've been offered a scholarship from another institution.

Comment: The thing is that Ecole Polytechnique will run another admission cycle from March-April, and it will be awarding scholarships to students admitted in that cycle as well. So I am guessing that there vacancies available if only, they could give me a second chance....

Comment: If you don't have a good reason for reconsideration, it won't go anywhere. Most of the applicants need the scholarship to attend - you are not unique in this situation. After all, that is why they have scholarships.

Comment: @JonCuster thank you for your comment. The thing is that I feel that the scholarship committee believes that I can manage my education without the scholarship because they've asked for my financial details. However, the details are 2 years old and since then there have been changes in my family's financial position. Do you think that this is a good enough reason for them to reconsider me?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

**Give Yourself another Chance**

You can conduct your second try during the next scholarship application cycle - and the time frame of a cycle varies between scholarship providers. Some scholarship providers have an all-year round application cycle, which means you can re-apply for a scholarship as soon as you hear of your unsuccessful application. On the other hand, the time period of other scholarship providers' application cycles is more limited, only allowing you to make a second application a year later.

**Write an Appeal Letter**

While it is recommended that the next application cycle would be the time you attempt your second try, it also wouldn't hurt to submit an appeal letter to the scholarship provider directly.

In your letter, reiterate that you are trying to apply for the scholarship a second time (even you got a scholarship with another institute but you prefer this one). Make them aware that you are not one to give up after a failed attempt, and are more eager than ever to receive the scholarship in question. Apart from your determination to reach your goals, this will also speak volumes about your courageous, indefatigable spirit.

**All in all,** it is important to allow your humility and sincerity to shine through in your letter, or in your interview if you are given a second chance. And if, in the end, you do not secure the scholarship of your dreams, don't be disheartened - work towards your career goal anyway. You can always do well in university and clinch a college scholarship, one that comes with no bond and essential financial support. There are many paths towards your end-goal and you should never put out the fire of your hope.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. It's really encouraging, I'll get to working on the appeal letter.

Comment: @Supermario your welcome... No Pain No Gain ;)

Comment: Is this based on data or at least your own experience? Because in my experience writing an appeal letter is somewhere between useless and actively hurtful, **especially** if the best reason you can find is *"but I really wanna have this scholarship"*. This comes dangerously close to wasting the committee's time. As for re-applying - this is certainly possible, but you should consider if the grounds on which you have been rejected this time will have changed or not.